# Send data to Google Sheet with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to send data to a google sheet with an HTML form. I followed this tutorial to do it : https://medium.com/@dmccoy/how-to-submit-an-html-form-to-google-sheets-without-google-forms-b833952cc175

I didn't used Google Form, because I needed specific javascript function. Google script app could do it, but it require users to log in to their google account to authorize it, and I don't want that.

So, in one hand, I have a google app project, with the code provided by the tutorial, who can received GET data, and write it in my Google Sheet. In the other hand, I have an html form who send the data to the google app script project.

But it seems that my poor knowledge in javascript and jquery made me fail something, even if almost all the code is already written. I think it come from AJAX, something is defintely wrong with that part. Here is the code (I have reduced the form because it's not really important, just wanted to show you that I'm not submitting the form with input type="submit" but with HTML5 validation, in case it would change something).

```js
$('#commerce').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('sending');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/*******/exec',
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: $('#commerce').serializeObject(),
        success: function(json, statut){alert('succes');},
        error: function(json, statut, erreur){alert('error');},
        complete: function(resultat, statut){alert('complete');}
    });
    alert('AJAX finished');
});
```

```html
<form id="commerce">
 <label for="horaire">Horaires de livraison : </label>
 <textarea name="horaire" rows="5" cols="75" placeholder="Ex : lundi entre 12h et 23h, mardi entre 18h et 23h... 
Prévoyez les horaires sur le plus de jours possible, au cas où nous ne pourrions honorer votre commande rapidement." maxlength="1000" required></textarea>
 <br>
 <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

I know that the onsubmit event is correctly linked, because the alert('sending') is siplayed only when I click on the button, and every fields are correct. 
But no other alert are displayed. I thought at list error or success should be triggered.

Can someone see my mistakes ? Thanks in advance, and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an other tutoriel that shows how to send data from a web form to Google Form (who will send the data to Google Sheet). And it works! So, it seems that Google Form is an easier solution than Google App Script to send data in AJAX to Google Sheet.

Here is the tutorial link : https://wiki.base22.com/btg/send-data-to-google-docs-using-a-web-form-and-ajax-72942000.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a more current jQuery and output, maybe it's a jQuery version thing?

This seems to work for me:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: sheetAppUrl,
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: $form.serializeObject()
      }).done(
        function(__e){
            console.log('Remote sheet updated!',__e);
        }
      ).fail(function(__e){
          console.log('Remote sheet update failed',__e);
      });
```